# can I do the equivalent of a C cast on an array in F#?

Tags: .net, f#

I have large array of this type:

```
type TradeData =    
    {
        Timestamp:          DateTime
        Instrument:         Instrument
        Price:              decimal
        Quantity:           decimal
        Direction:          Direction
    }
```

We're talking about several gigabytes loaded every time during debugging.
The data is stored on the disk in binary using FSPickler which is much faster than Json, but it still takes a long time to load.
I sped it up by slicing the file into chunks of 1h and loading them in parallel, but we're still taking 15-20 seconds at the start of every debugging session.

What I would like to know is if I can put the data in an array, write the array as a binary blob.
Then I'd load the blob and do something like:

```
myData = (TradeData *) pBinaryBlob
```

I'm not sure if this is doable under dotnet, or if each object really needs to be initialized independently.

Comment: `Instrument` and `Direction` are reference types or structs?

Comment: Direction is a 2 values DU that could be summed as a book; but Instrument is a ref type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can probably be done provided you use `struct`s rather than objects. If you have already serialised the file as objects you may need to re-serialise the file once to bit-align with the structs or [carefully annotate your struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind?view=net-6.0#system-runtime-interopservices-layoutkind-explicit) with the necessary byte alignments.

If you read the `FileStream` into byte buffers I'd then look at using either [nativeptr<'T>](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-nativeinterop-nativeptrmodule.html) or `(ReadOnly)Span<'T>` and [`MemoryMarshal.Cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.cast?view=net-6.0) to perform an `unsafe` conversion.